# 12 seconds delay in DNS queries - Windows 2019

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ibm, windows-server-2019

Resolving any hostname takes 12 seconds on a new Windows 2019 server on baremetal, but only when using the system-default DNS servers instead of directly querying one.

I can reproduce it reliably with these powershell commands:

```
#these are fast
Resolve-DnsName google.com -server 10.0.80.11
Resolve-DnsName google.com -server 10.0.80.12

#this takes 12 seconds before it prints out the response
Resolve-DnsName google.com
```

The hostname being resolved doesn't matter, and in this example 10.0.80.11 and 10.0.80.12 happen to be the two DNS servers set on both network interfaces:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-DnsClientServerAddress

InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
PublicNetwork-Teamed                13 IPv4    {10.0.80.11, 10.0.80.12}
PublicNetwork-Teamed                13 IPv6    {}
PrivateNetwork-Teamed                7 IPv4    {10.0.80.11, 10.0.80.12}
PrivateNetwork-Teamed                7 IPv6    {}
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1 IPv4    {}
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1 IPv6    {}
```

Nslookup doesn't show this behavior (it's always fast), but that uses its own way of resolving DNS that differ from what the OS actually does.

Using ping or internet explorer (or any other program) with hostnames not yet in the local dns cache will show the same 12 seconds delay.

The server has two teamed network connections, one for a private network (that acts as a 10.0.0.0/8 through vlan magic) and one for the public internet. Both connections are set up with static IP and DNS addresses. It doesn't matter which DNS servers are set.
[image: network connections]

What I've tried to troubleshoot:

- windows update (from 2019 RTM, to 2019 cumulative update August 2020, to 2019 preview of cumulative update August 2020)
- tried setting other DNS servers (from the IBM Cloud DNS, our own private DNS, and public DNS like 8.8.8.8)
- disabled the "IBM USB Remote NDIS Network Device" - no idea what it's for, maybe IPMI?
- updated the network card (Intel X710-T4) drivers
- updated the network card firmware
- tried disabling IPv6
- disabled the firewall
- disabled windows defender
- rebooted multiple times
- prayed

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-DnsClient

InterfaceAlias               Interface ConnectionSpecificSuffix ConnectionSpecificSuffix RegisterThisConn UseSuffixWhen
                             Index                              SearchList               ectionsAddress   Registering
--------------               --------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ---------------- -------------
PublicNetwork-Teamed                13                          {}                       True             False
PrivateNetwork-Teamed                7                          {}                       True             False
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1                          {}                       True             False

PS C:\Users\Administrator> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : doomed
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : example.net
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : example.net

Ethernet adapter PublicNetwork-Teamed:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-FD-FE-01-23-45
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1234:5678:90ab:cd::3(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1234:5678:90ab:cd:ef12:3456:7890:abcd(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b154:f38e:26ae:1e71%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1.2.3.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 1234:5678:90ab:cd::1
                                       1.2.3.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 305987070
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-E0-4F-3A-3C-FD-FE-83-CB-41
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.80.11
                                       10.0.80.12
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter PrivateNetwork-Teamed:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-FD-FE-01-23-44
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e591:3764:3ca2:7734%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.2.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.192
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 222100990
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-26-E0-4F-3A-3C-FD-FE-83-CB-41
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.80.11
                                       10.0.80.12
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Any idea what's going on or what I should look for next?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you capture network trafic from this server, with wireshark for example, and see what you can find in there ?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I tried that and it showed what was going on!
The query would go out at the same time on both the public and private network interfaces. It would immediately receive a response over the private interface and timeout and retry multiple times over the public interface. https://imgur.com/TGBxBrT  I've removed the DNS server addresses from the public interface and now everything is fast again.

Comment: I'm not sure why it became an issue on this particular server, since that's the default configuration of all the windows servers delivered by IBM "Cloud", and that's not the first windows 2019 we have.. but I'm glad it works now. Feel free to add that as an answer so I can upvote you one more time :)

Comment: Great ! I can't see your screenshot unfortunately but the documentation says that the 12 seconds delay occurs when no answer is received : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn593685(v=ws.11)#dns-client-resolver-behavior